Connection to NATS server gives "tls: failed to verify certificate: x509"
I am working with a remote NATS server. I have a user jwt and I want to connect to nats server by using this jwt. When I create a new context by running this command;
nats context save <context_name> --server <server_name> --creds "<path_to_cred_file>"

The context is created successfully. However, whenever I use this context to interact with NATS server by running;
nats s ls --context <context_name>

It gives me the following error;
nats: error: setup failed: tls: failed to verify certificate: x509: “<certificate_name>” certificate is not trusted

This error is really strange because I didnt enable tls authentication for my connection. I just want to use jwt file to connect to server.
Can someone guide me how to resolve this issue?
I tried to check the connection to nats server through telnet;
telnet <server_name> 4222

and it produces the following output;
Trying <server_ip>...
Connected to <server_name>.
Escape character is '^]'.
INFO {"server_id":"<server_id>","server_name":"<server_name>","version":"2.10.14","proto":1,"git_commit":"","go":"go1.21.9","host":"0.0.0.0","port":4222,"headers":true,"auth_required":true,"tls_required":true,"max_payload":1048576,"jetstream":true,"client_id":<id>,"client_ip":"<client_ip>","nonce":"<nonce>","cluster":"<cluster>","domain":"<domain>","xkey":"<xkey>"} 
Connection closed by foreign host.


Without knowing the server configuration or your credentials file I can only speculate. However cryptographic keys are used when authenticating with a JWT.
From https://docs.nats.io/running-a-nats-service/configuration/securing_nats/auth_intro/jwt#the-authentication-process

When a User connects to a server, it presents a JWT issued by its Account. The user proves its identity by signing a server-issued cryptographic challenge with its private key. The signature verification validates that the signature is attributable to the user's public key.

From https://docs.nats.io/using-nats/developer/connecting/creds

To help make connecting with a JWT easier, the client libraries support the concept of a credentials file. This file contains both the private key and the JWT and can be generated with the nsc tool.

Your specific error tls: failed to verify certificate: x509: “<certificate_name>” certificate is not trusted leads me to believe that the certificate expired, became corrupted, or is not the correct one.
